# How to prevent others from copying my mathJAX code in browsers?

Tags: mathjax

In web browsers, people can right-click/hold on a math equation (s) and "view TEX commands". From there they can copy entire math code.

This is very problematic if your website/blog is math related. It takes a lot of time and work to write these equations, and some scammer can easily copy your TEX code and paste it in his website without having to do any work.

Is it possible to prevent TEX commands from being copied ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I fear your question is off topic here ... Better ask this question on an page for browser issues ...

Comment: I think you can config MathJax by setting `menuSettings: {texHints: false}`, see [doc for `menuSettings`](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/hub.html).

Comment: On the other hand, it could be a good thing to make it easy for other people to copy and modify your equations. Maybe they will write a blog post themselves with a nice new insight or useful explanation that they would not have written if they didn't have had access to your code (because they don't have sufficient knowledge of MathJax/TeX, for example). Of course ideally they would provide proper attribution to you/your original post, but even without attribution it could be a valuable contribution to the discussion on the topic that you have made possible by sharing your source code.

Comment: this is off topic here (it is a javascript question not tex), mathjax has a standard configuration option to disable its right menu, but that is not offering any security, anyone can view source of the entire page or simply save the web page from the browser menu.